# How to display validator error message for grid cell where space is so tight?

Tags: asp.net

I have a required field validator and a range validator for a cell in my grid as follows :

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtItemQuantity" Width="75%" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ReqValItemQuantity" ControlToValidate="txtItemQuantity" ErrorMessage="Invalid Quantity" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RanValQuantity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtItemQuantity" MinimumValue="0"  MaximumValue="99"  ErrorMessage="Invalid Quantity" Text="Invalid Quantity"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

The problem is that this leaves up a very large empty space in my grid for each row which is not convinient:

[image]

My questions is, is there a different way of displaying an error message without letting it mess up the grid design ? I thought of something similar to the TextMode error style of the TextBox like below but i'm not sure how to perform this ?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design.

Comment: But not asking for help in a better design, i'm asking for how to display the error message in a popup like the attached screenshot or any ideas similar to that so that there is no empty spaces in my grid.

Comment: you can try to use jquery append function for this stuation. Define your message div out of your wrapper and append it on anywhere http://api.jquery.com/appendto/